# How to convert const char* to char*

Tags: c++, string, const-correctness

can any body tell me how to conver const char* to char*?

```
get_error_from_header(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data) {
    ErrorMsg *error = (ErrorMsg *)data;
    char* err = strstr((const char *)ptr,"550");
    //error  cannot convert const char** to char*
    if(err) {
        strncpy(error->data,(char*)ptr,LENGTH_ERROR_MESSAGE-1);
        error->data[LENGTH_ERROR_MESSAGE-1] = '\0';
        error->ret = true;
    }
    return size*nmemb;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't appear to use `err` in the rest of that function, so why bother creating it?

```
if (NULL != strstr((const char *)ptr, "550"))
{
```

If you do need it, will you really need to modify whatever it points to? If not, then declare it as `const` also:

```
const char* err = strstr((const char *)ptr, "550");
```

Finally, as casts are such nasty things, it is best to use a specific modern-style cast for the operation you want to perform. In this case:

```
if (NULL != strstr(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(ptr), "550"))
{
```

Answer (score 17):

There are a few things I don't understand here. I see that this is tagged for [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), but what I describe below should be the same as [Standard C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B).

#### Doesn't compile

The code you give doesn't compile; `get_error_from_header` does not specify a return type. In my experiments I made the return type `size_t`.

#### Signature of C++ `strstr()`

The signature for `strstr()` in the standard C library is:

```
char *
strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

but the signature for `strstr()` in the [C++ library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/), depending on the overload, is one of:

```
const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
      char * strstr (       char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

I would choose the first overload, because you don't want to modify the string, you only want to read it. Therefore you can change your code to:

```
const char* err = strstr((const char *)ptr, "550");
if (err != NULL) {
    ...
}
```

Also, I'm assuming your comment reporting the error:

```
//error  cannot convert const char** to char*
```

is a typo: there's no `const char**` to be seen.

#### Assignment to `err` unnecessary

As is pointed out in a previous answer, the use of `err` to store the result of `strstr` is unnecessary if all it's used for is checking `NULL`. Therefore you could use:

```
if (strstr((const char *)ptr, "550") != NULL) {
    ...
}
```

#### Use of `reinterpret_cast<>` encouraged

As is pointed out in another answer you should be using `reinterpret_cast<>` instead of C-style casts:

```
if (strstr(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(ptr), "550") != NULL) {
    ...
}
```

#### Use of `const_cast<>` to strip `const`

Given the example in the question, I don't see where this is necessary, but if you had a variable that you need to strip of `const`-ness, you should use the `const_cast<>` operator. As in:

```
const char * p1;
char * p2;

p2 = const_cast<char *>(p1);
```

As is pointed out in a comment, the reason to use `const_cast<>` operator is so that the author's intention is clear, and also to make it easy to search for the use of `const_cast<>`; usually stripping const is the source of bugs or a design flaw.

Comment: I think "const char** to char*" was just a typo.  And I agree that there's no point in creating a variable if it's never used.  So I basically agree with your "Unnecessary const-ing" code, except I'm not clear on the benefit of reinterpret_cast.

Comment: You're quoting the signature of strtr() from C, not C++.

Comment: One more reason to use const_cast is that it is easier to search. By simply searching in the code for "const_cast" keyword you can find all the places where the developer changed the constness. This is good because constness change usually is a source for problems/bugs.

Comment: The benefit of reinterpret_cast is that the void *ptr won't work as a char * parameter (const or not), depending on the compiler/settings. Also, in C++ using the casting operators such as reinterpret_cast instead of C-style cast gives you the benefit of knowing what the original author's intent was in casting, and being able to search for such casts.

Comment: @MSalters mentions that I'm quoting the signature of strstr() from C, not C++; what is the signature of the C++ strstr()? Is this a C++/CLI difference, that strstr() has a different signature under C++ than C?

Comment: C strstr has one signature (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strstr.html),  char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);  C++ has two (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/), const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 ); and char * strstr (       char * str1, const char * str2 );  Note that neither of these matches the C signature.

Comment: Thanks for p2 = const_cast<char *>(p1); that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You did mention that the use of reinterpret_cast<> is encouraged, could you help on understand why if at all that is a bad choice as compared to const_cast<>.

Answer (score 8):

Can't you just do:

```
char* err = strstr((char *)ptr,"550");
```

The error is because if you pass in a const char* to strstr you get one out (because of the overload).

Comment: True.  It depends what he's ultimately going to do with it (currently nothing except check for NULL)

Answer (score 5):

//try this instead:

```
const char* mstr="";
char* str=const_cast<char*>(mstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well is ptr (which you passed in as void*) actually const or not? (In other words, is the memory under your control?) If it's not, then cast it to char* instead of const char* when calling strstr. If it is, however, you'll get a const char* out (pointing to a location inside of the string pointed to by ptr), and will then need to strncpy out to another string which you are responsible for managing.

Answer (score 0):

According to my deep research I have found numerous forums that have no direct solution or a reference answer to this question, I then delve into the GCC online documentation giving a brief read for their compiler properly docs and this is what I can provide.

In GNU C, pointers to arrays with qualifiers work similar to pointers to other qualified types. For example, a value of type int (*)[5] can be used to initialize a variable of type const int (*)[5]. These types however aren't compatible in ISO C because the const qualifier is formally attached to the element type of the array and not the array itself.

This description might be better understood if we take this

```
extern void
transpose (int N, int M, double out[M][N], const double in[N][M]);
double x[3][2];
double y[2][3];
…
transpose(3, 2, y, x);
```

Observing the above is that if you had an

```
s1=createStudent(s1, 123, "Poli");
s2=createStudent(s2, 456, "Rola);
```

Whereas the const char[5] for both "Poli" and "Rola" have correlation to a char a[]. It is strictly not permitted as each element has the qualifier attached and not the entire array as a const.