# winpcap findalldevs const char * incompatible to char *

Tags: c++, winpcap

I have installed WinPcap, the Developer pack, created a new project and adjusted the compiler/linker settings. I use the [very basic example](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut1.html) from WinPCap's homepage ("obtaining the device list"). But I get the error:

```
The argument of type "" const char * "" is incompatible with the parameter "" char * "".
```

in the line where the function `pcap_findalldevs_ex()` is called. I already tried all the casts mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833034/how-to-convert-const-char-to-char).

```
#include "pcap.h"

main()
{
    pcap_if_t *alldevs;
    pcap_if_t *d;
    int i=0;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    /* Retrieve the device list from the local machine */
    if (pcap_findalldevs_ex(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING, NULL /* auth is not needed */, &alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in pcap_findalldevs_ex: %s\n", errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Print the list */
    for(d= alldevs; d != NULL; d= d->next)
    {
        printf("%d. %s", ++i, d->name);
        if (d->description)
            printf(" (%s)\n", d->description);
        else
            printf(" (No description available)\n");
    }

    if (i == 0)
    {
        printf("\nNo interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.\n");
        return;
    }

    /* We don't need any more the device list. Free it */
    pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean not the first parameter PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING is wrong, instead the error buffer is? I just havent modified the code from the example, its my first touch into winpcap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
if (pcap_findalldevs_ex(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING, NULL /* auth is not needed */, &alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
```

The `PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING` constant is a preprocessor macro that maps to a narrow **string literal**:

```
#define PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING   "rpcap://"
```

The first parameter of `pcap_findalldevs_ex()` expects a **non-const** `char*` pointer:

```
int pcap_findalldevs_ex(
    char *source,
    struct pcap_rmtauth *auth,
    pcap_if_t **alldevs,
    char *errbuf     
)
```

In C++, a narrow string literal is of type `const char[]`, which decays to `const char*`.  You cannot pass a `const char*` pointer where a non-const `char*` pointer is expected.  Older C++ compilers *may* have allowed it, but starting in C++11 this is *required* to be an error.

However, in this particular case, you can safely cast away the const-ness, as `pcap_findalldevs_ex()` does not write data to the `source` parameter:

```
pcap_findalldevs_ex(const_cast<char*>(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING), ...)
```

If you don't want to do that, you will have to make a local non-const copy of the string data first:

```
char szSource[] = PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING;
pcap_findalldevs_ex(szSource, ...)
```

Comment: Alternatively, compile the program as C not C++.